# Running the script to invoke command in terminal

Tags: python, bash, shell, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to run it on the raspbian, the terminal pops up and stays blank/vanishes can anyone tell me why is this happening and how can I prevent this from happening , Kindly advice and thank you in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONPATH=$1/env
nohup x-terminal-emulator -e $1/env/bin/python 
$1/Web_Server/run/script.py
#---------
```

Comment: are you sure you can run your `x-terminal-emulator` in background with `nohup`?

Comment: can you try: `nohup xterm -hold -e $1/env/bin/python $1/Web_Server/run/script.py` ?? Note that `$1/env/bin/python` and `$1/Web_Server/run/script.py` should be on the same line!!!

Comment: Thanks xterm -hold -e did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing `x-terminal-emulator` by `xterm -hold -e` in the bash script we could manage to pop up a new terminal and run python!

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONPATH=$1/env
nohup xterm -hold -e $1/env/bin/python $1/Web_Server/run/script.py
```